# Scroll to Top script doesn't work in Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I added a scroll to top script to my website (developed with Bootstrap 4) and it doesn't work. However this script works on the same website which was developed with Bootstrap 3. I think that there's an error occurred with bootstrap version, but unfortunately I can't find the issue.

```html
<div class="toTop">
  <a href="#"><i class="icon-arrow-up icons"></i></a>
</div>
```

```js
$('.toTop').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');         
});
```

Console log:

```
JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1
smooth.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at smooth.js:2
(anonymous) @ smooth.js:2
```

Comment: Put a `console.log()` in the click handler to check if it's even being called

Comment: The log is:

JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1
smooth.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at smooth.js:2
(anonymous) @ smooth.js:2

Comment: You should use full version of jquery https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js

Comment: @proofzy Good answer. I forgot BS4 uses jQuery slim

Comment: Hi Rory, jQuerry is loaded via

 // include custom jQuery
function shapeSpace_include_custom_jquery() {
 wp_deregister_script('jquery');
 wp_enqueue_script('jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js', array(), null, true);
}

function in my functions.php file

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan just want to explain more clearer. This issue appeared on the Wordpress website built with Bootstrap 4. jQurry loads from functions.php file with the function I've provided above.

Comment: Update jquery to 3.1.1 to see what happens, change  'ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js' to  'ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'

Comment: @Troyer thanks, already changed the version but unfortunately nothing happened

Answer (score 1):

I have included Bootstrap 4 and full jQuery 3.3.1 and it works fine. 
Maybe you have  an excess code which makes you errors.

Your jQuery script works fine:

```
$('.toTop').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');         
});
```

I made a simple [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/238717/) for you.

Note: Bootstrap 4 uses jQuery slim but also full jQuery is supported. 
For your example you should use **full jQuery**.

Comment: Thanks, but in my case jQuery loads not from the scripts below the footer, but via functions.php (that's Wordpress based website). 

If I put the jQuery loading script below the footer everything is fine. But if you're loading jQuery from functions.php, the script doesn't work.

Comment: @Morgari Find what is jQuery version there included and give me details

Comment: That's a 3.1.1 version there

Comment: @Morgari Okay, I have selected jQuery version 3.1.1. and everything works fine. Try with my jsfiddle again.. https://imgur.com/a/3nCvrde

Comment: thanks. I'll write this once again:  in my case jQuery loads not from the scripts below the footer, but via functions.php (that's Wordpress based website). If I put the jQuery loading script below the footer everything is fine. But if you're loading jQuery from functions.php, the script doesn't work.

So yes, everything is fine with jQ v3.1.1
but I have an issue with jQuery loaded from functions.php

Comment: @Morgari read something [here](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-properly-add-javascripts-and-styles-in-wordpress/), maybe this will help to you.. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="toTop" onclick="gotoTop()">BACK TO TOP<div class="icon-arrow-up icons"></div></div>

function gotoTop() {
   $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0},'fast');
}
```

Try this out..

Comment: Just hit the gotoTop function definition in the browser console and see, this'll surely work.

Comment: That doesn't work in my case - when you're loading the jQuery via functions.php

Answer (score 0):

WordPress loads its own jQuery library in what is known as ‘no conflict mode‘ and the $ selector or variable that defines jQuery doesn’t work with the WordPress loaded jQuery version, so it has to be expressed more like so…

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

// Code goes here


});
```

Here we are using jQuery at the beginning of the document ready function and then passing or binding that to the $ selector, so now anywhere else in the code you can use the $ selector.

https://wpbeaches.com/jquery-document-ready-function-for-wordpress/

Comment: Please apply suitable code formatting options available in Stackoverflow editor.